# How to add item to Quick setting?

Tags: java, android

I don't know the name of these shapes but i call it button by the way what are their name? and how can we make this in android programming using java.I see that some Apps has these feature that you when you swipe down the screen there is list that you can have your feature like this ADM features i don't meant the shape or vector or like this.
[image]

Comment: [This](https://android.jlelse.eu/develop-a-custom-tile-with-quick-settings-tile-api-74073e849457) article will surely help. Also, you can further check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424914/how-to-add-an-item-to-quick-settings-in-android) answer on StackOverflow but the article is the one you should go for.

Comment: And these shapes are known as Tiles and with the location, Quick Setting Tiles.

Comment: yes but at the end all say that we can't add item too quick setting but i don't know how ADM can

Comment: Because you can add them, it's just that there are limited latest resources. The [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/develop-a-custom-tile-with-quick-settings-tile-api-74073e849457) I'd shared with you consists the complete implementation. It has already mentioned the [official Tile API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/Tile.html) was added in API 23.